# Vector triple product proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

**Vector triple product**
[image: Proof of a × ( b × c )]

How did the author arrive at the step 2 from step 1 in the above definition of a × ( b × c )?

What is your explanation?

Comment: I evaded complicated calculations in my answer to https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/586954/help-with-vector-cross-product-identity/587199#587199

Comment: Why couldn't i see the added picture of main part of the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:\begin{align}(a_2c_2+a_3c_3)b_1-(a_2b_2+a_3b_3)c_1&=(a_2c_2+a_3c_3)b_1\color{red}{+a_1c_1b_1}-(a_2b_2+a_3b_3)c_1\color{red}{-a_1c_1b_1}\\&=(a_1c_1+a_2c_2+a_3c_3)b_1-(a_1b_1+a_2b_2+a_3b_3)c_1.\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The reason the following holds

$$(a_2 c_2 + a_3 c_3)b_1 - (a_2 b_2 + a_3 b_3)c_1=
(a_1 c_1 + a_2 c_2 + a_3 c_3)b_1 - (a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 + a_3 b_3)c_1$$

is because on the right hand side the following was added:

$$(a_1 c_1)b_1 - (a_1 b_1)c_1 = a_1 b_1 c_1 - a_1 b_1 c_1 = 0$$

One is free to add something equal to zero anywhere.